# why is g:link ignoring request params?

Tags: grails, gsp

In my Grails app, I have a URL mapped directly to a view in `UrlMappings.groovy`

```
"/geolocation"(view: "/geolocation/index")
```

I'm trying to generate a link to this view that includes request parameters with:

```
<g:link elementId="btnSrcDest" uri="/geolocation" class="mapInfo" 
        params="[mapType: 'foo']">
    Click me
</g:link>
```

But this generates the following HTML

```
<a class="mapInfo" id="btnSrcDest" href="/myApp/geolocation">
    Click me
</a>
```

Whereas I was expecting this:

```
<a class="mapInfo" id="btnSrcDest" href="/myApp/geolocation?mapType=foo">
    Click me
</a>
```

Why is the `params` attribute of `g:link` being ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `uri` attribute then that is assumed to be the complete (webapp-relative) link and no further processing will happen.  You could try making it a named URL mapping instead

```
name geo:"/geolocation" {
  view = "/geolocation/index"
}
```

and then use

```
<g:link elementId="btnSrcDest" mapping="geo" class="mapInfo" 
        params="[mapType: 'foo']">
```